# ajax request call ending with error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with ajax call. I want to pass information on the server side but always when I call ajax request it ends with error. Weird is, that I used exactly the same code, same lines, in previous project.

This is my ajax request (php_session_id is not undefined, I'm checking that every time):

```
$.ajax({
        data: { unique: php_session_id },
        url: 'server/uploading_files.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("response");

        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("some error");
        }
    });
```

And this is my uploading_files.php file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
session_start();

if( isset( $_POST['unique'] ) ) {$_SESSION['unique_id'] = $_POST['unique'];}

$path_to_save = 'upload/' . $_SESSION['unique_id'] . '/';
if( !is_dir( $path_to_save ) ) {
    if ( !mkdir( $path_to_save, 0777, true ) ) {
        die('Failed to create folder for uploaded photos...');
    }
}
```

Error codes when I use

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
```

are:

> jqXHR - Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "Failed to create folder
>   for uploaded photos...", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
>
> textStatus - parsererror
>
> errorThrown - SyntaxError: Unexpected token F(…)

Don't you have any idea how to solve it, please?

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is.

Comment: Output the PHP error. That will probably tell you how to solve it.

Comment: How can I get this error code please?

Comment: Turn on error reporting in PHP. Look at your developer console after you make the AJAX request.

Comment: There you go, you do see your error message in there **dont you?**

Comment: I do now but I have no idea why it doesn't want to create folder..

Comment: If you are on unix/linux its likely to be a permission issue

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it's because your PHP return's nothing. Try to setup `echo "something here"` and look how is it going.
2. Go to **network** tab in chrome console and check what code is returned by your request.

Comment: I tried this echo stuff but nothing happend.

Comment: Is your dir `$path_to_save` is correct?